# Multi Agent system for Android devices

Tags: multi-agent

I'm planning on implementing a multi agent system for Android. I have already went through JADE and JaCa-Android. Both projects are obsolete. Can anyone who has worked with multi agent systems can suggest me a way to start the project? Thanks.